# Is there a way to get custom user model password before it gets hashed on Django

Tags: python, django

A custom user model was created in Django. After we create a user, we then send that user details to firebase:

```
# Sync User to FireBase Authentication:
@receiver(post_save, sender=Account)
def add_user_to_firebase(sender, created, instance, *args, **kwargs): 
  if created:
    auth.create_user(**{
            "uid":instance.firebase_uid,
            "display_name": instance.username, 
            "email": instance.email,
            "password": instance.password
        })
```

but this is where the issue comes in: when we send the password `instance.password` the password is then hashed before it gets sent to firebase. We want the unhashed password to get sent to firebase instead. Is that possible?

Comment: Storing users passwords in plaintext is a security/confidentially flaw, why would you want to do this?

Comment: sounds like `instance` is a user model instance. Django converting passwords to hash automatically on creating model, so just pass password externally as separated argument: `add_user_to_firebase(sender, created, instance, plain_password, *args, **kwargs)`. and `"password": plain_password`. However previous comment is more correct

Comment: @IainShelvington [`firebase.auth.create_user`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#create_user) takes the **raw, unhashed** password. However, firebase stores it hashed.